# Maximisation problem for a quasi-linear utility function

Tags: optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

How do I solve a maximisation problem for a quasi-linear utility
function:
max $U(x, y) = 2x + \ln (1 + y)$ s.t. $x + y ≤ 5, x ≥ 0, y ≥ 0$ ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackexchange! Questions phrased as "do this for me" usually aren't received well. Be sure to show your attempts at the question so we know how to help you.